# React Native importing only what is needed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Say I have the following:

```
import validator from 'validator'
```

and in my code do:

```
validator.isEmail(txt)
```

Would that import the entire `validator` and increase the overall package size?

---

if, how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement will import the whole validator. 
What are you looking for is this

```
    import { isEmail } from ‘validator’
```

isEmail should be e exported in the source file.